# How split data frame at irregular intervals?

Tags: r, dataframe, split, intervals

I have data frame and would like to split table at intervals of value equal to 200. I tried to do as in the following example, but it does not work correctly. Please help because I need to quickly deal with it.

```
TD$wW=(c(0, cumsum(diff(TD$wZ) == 200)))

1   200     1
2   452     1
3   54      1
4   0       1
5   200     2
6   123     2
7   0       2
8   200     3
9   466     3
10  1223    3
11  4522    3
12  10665   3
13  30425   3
14  57730   3
15  139565  3
16  403784  3
17  200     3
18  28      3
19  0       3
```

Comment: `split(TD, TD$wW)` won't work?

Comment: Works, only note that the last three rows in the table should have a value of 4 and this is my problem.

Comment: `z=df$X200==200;c(1,cumsum(z)+1)`.

Comment: Oh, then simply `split(TD, cumsum(TD$wZ == 200))`

Comment: It was so easy, thanks!!